# C++ Equivalent for GetLocalTime in Linux (with milliseconds!)

Tags: c++, c, linux, time, raspberry-pi

I have been searching for over an hour but I simply seem to not be able to find the solution!

I am looking for a function that gives me a similar struct as GetLocalTime on Windows does. The important thing for me is that this struct has hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

`localtime()` does not include milliseconds and therefore I cannot use it!

I would apprechiate a solution that uses the standard library or another very small library since I am working on a Raspberry Pi and connot use large libraries like boost!

Comment: How about [`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)? Or [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) if you want even higher precision?

Comment: FWIW, Windows' `GetLocalTime` function doesn't provide millisecond precision... the `wMilliseconds` field will only update at about 15Hz (i.e. you get the same value for ~66ms, then see a value ~66ms greater for the next ~66ms).

Comment: @TonyD That's a general problem.  The Posix `clock_gettime` functions return nanoseconds, but there's no guarantee that the actual granularity is anywhere near a nanosecond either.

Comment: @JamesKanze: sure, but this question emphasises the need for actual millisecond accuracy - *"does not include milliseconds and therefore I cannot use it"* - so I'm just pointing out that need might not be quite so emphatic given the timing wasn't that accurate pre-port....

Comment: @TonyD Yes.  Given that, he wouldn't be far worse just by multiplying the results of `time` by 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetLocalTime` is not a usual Linux function.

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), you probably want [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), or (as commented by [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg)), the older [gettimeofday(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html)

If you need some `struct` giving all of hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds you have to code that yourself using [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) and explicitly computing the millisecond part.

Something like the below code is printing the time with milliseconds

```
 struct timespec ts = {0,0};
 struct tm tm = {};
 char timbuf[64];
 if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts))
    { perror("clock_gettime"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
 time_t tim = ts.tv_sec;
 if (localtime(&tim, &tm))
    { perror("localtime"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
 if (strftime(timbuf, sizeof(timbuf), "%D %T", &tm))
     { perror("strftime"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};
 printf("%s.%03d\n", timbuf, (int)(ts.tv_nsec/1000000));
```

Comment: Calling gettimeofday "older" makes it sound as if it not as good. But in fact, gettimeofday has been aggressively optimized on Linux so that no call into kernel space is required. See [man vdso](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html). Note: this will probably not help OP since I doubt this optimization is implemented on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This works! I am using a slightly different code but I am using the same priciple!

Comment: @flodin Posix documents `gettimeofday` as obsolescent, and says to use `clock_gettime` instead.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's true. You'll simply have to make a judgement call on what is more important to your application. I doubt gettimeofday is going away within the next 10 years though. In the mean time, maybe similar optimizations will be implemented for clock_gettime. Edit: just saw Basile's comment, so just ignore my comments.

Answer (score 2):

As it was mentioned above, there are not direct equivalent. If you can use C++ 11, `<chrono>` header allows to get the same result, but not in single call. You can use `high_resolution_clock` to get current Unix time in milliseconds, then you can get `localtime` C function to get time without milliseconds, and use current Unix time in milleseconds to find milliseconds count. It looks like you will have to write your own `GetLocalTime` implementation, but with C++ 11 it will not be complex.

Comment: Copiling with C++ 11 needs so much more time (2 minutes vs 10 seconds). So I will be going with the other solution. But thanks anyways!

Comment: It is your choise, but for me program runtime performance and portability is important, and compilation performance is not important at all; you have to compile it one time only during 2 minutes, and your users will use it for months ;) From the other hand, C++ 11 features are more portable than Linux system calls. You can have one function implementation for Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc, instead of conditional compilation with system call/Windows API (of course, if you write portable software).

Comment: If you could provide at least a minimal code example I would save at least 30 minutes of pointless research and trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of:

- `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)`; returns local time, up to millisecond (of course constrained by the actual clock resolution); does not care of local timezone information, returns UTC time. Just use millisecond information (from `tv_nsec` field).
- `time()`; returns local time, up to the second - no millisecond - also UTC time. `time()` results (a `time_t`) is easy to convert to the final format.
- then convert time() result using `localtime_r()`; this sets up a structure very similar to Windows `SYSTEMTIME`; result is up to the second, and takes into account local timezone information.
- finally set up the millisecond field using `clock_gettime()` results.

These routines are documented, not deprecated, portable.
You may need to call `tzset()` once (this sets the timezone information - a C global variable - from operating system environment - probably a heavy operation).